# NestJS integration with rabbitmq- specify exchange name

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I am integrating a NestJS application with RabbitMQ and i followed this [tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq)
From the tutorial i can see that message consumer can connect to the rabbitMQ broker using a queue name, but actually i want to create a temporary queue that connects to an exchange. I cannot find an option to specify the exchange name in the queue options specified in the tutorial. can someone please point to the right configuration to use to specify an exchange instead of queue?
is it possible to specify an exchange name inside the 'queueOptions' structure?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your tutorial (I don't know NestJS), `createMicroservice` only connects to a queue (or create it if needed). In other words, it performs `assertQueue` operation:

```js
var queue = 'task_queue';

channel.assertQueue(queue, {
  durable: false
});
```

If you want to bind a queue to an existing exchange, you need to perform `bindQueue` operation:

```js
channel.bindQueue(queue, exchange, '');
```

Thus you can't bind to an exchange using `queueOptions`. Take a look at the [official Rabbitmq documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html), especially the "Temporary queues" and following "Bindings" sections.